# Google cloud shell missing web preview button

Tags: shell, web, cloud, preview

I stepped away from my sample Transport-Tracker project, which had been working just fine.

Now, when I run the Google Cloud Shell, the web preview button is no longer present.  Also missing is the file transfer button.  The Cloud Shell only includes the "Send key combination" and "Terminal settings" buttons.

I've tried this in both IE and Chrome with the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I experience the same issue, but am connected to a project.

Answer (score 48):

This is due to a CSS bug. When you have the Google Cloud Platform navigation panel on the left opened, then open a Cloud Shell, the Web Preview button is pushed off the screen.

To fix, simply close the navigation panel by pressing the hamburger button in the top left. (You can reopen the panel, and the Web Preview button will be fixed.)

Comment: This resolved it for me as well. Screenshot of the issue here, showing where it should/does appear once you figure out how to toggle the menus: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/191564/30655824-13ae6b28-9e00-11e7-8161-89fee70b69b1.png

Comment: Geez, in a year this still hasn't been fixed. Thanks for your help here though!

Comment: This saved my day!, i was taking coursera course on ML with google cloud lab vm.

Comment: Lol yeah, this sort of bug is classic Google. Launch your distributed deep learning algorithm and watch it fly. Oh, you want Web Preview to view progress on tensorboard?... yeah that's a one line CSS fix that has taken us over a year to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Lo and behold, today the web preview icon appears.  I suspect it may have something to do with trying to open the full cloud shell before a connection to the projector has been established.

Comment: It does not appear on my mac but appear on my windows machine. funny!